# Recursion using promise api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

Please find the code here

http://plnkr.co/edit/zwCYGQaxyGyr7kL6fLKh?p=preview

I am trying to do recursion with an async function which uses promise. I wanted to happen it serially (so no $q.all), and want to wait till all the nodes are processed before the `then` of the main call to be fired. In other words, `You are exited` needs to be printed at the end. How can I do that?

thanks.

### program

```
var asyncPrint = function(val) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(console.log(val));
        //console.log(val);
      }, 1000);

      return deferred.promise;
    };


 var tree = {
      1: {node:1, ch: [2,3] },
      2: {node:2, ch: [4] },
      3: {node:3, ch: [] },
      4: {node:4, ch: [5] },
      5: {node:5, ch: [] }
    }

   function recur(tre, node) {
    return Async.asyncPrint(node)
      .then(function () {
        var ch = tre[node.node] ? tre[node.node].ch : []; 
        if(ch.length > 0 ){
            angular.forEach(ch, function (d) {
                return recur(tre, tre[d])
            })
        }
      })
  }

  recur(tree, tree[1]).then(function(){
    console.log('You are exited')
  })
```

### output

```
Object {node: 1, ch: Array[2]}
You are exited 
Object {node: 2, ch: Array[1]}
Object {node: 3, ch: Array[0]}
Object {node: 4, ch: Array[1]}
Object {node: 5, ch: Array[0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if(ch.length > 0 ){
>     angular.forEach(ch, function (d) {
>         return recur(tre, tre[d])
>     })
> }
> ```

That doesn't work - you don't return a promise here for when you are ready with the `recur` calls but just return `undefined`. You indeed want to use `all` here:

```
return $q.all(ch.map(function(d) {
    return recur(tre, tre[d]);
});
```

Or, for sequentially processing the `ch` array:

```
function next(i) {
    if (i<ch.length)
        return recur(tre, tre[ch[i]]).then(next.bind(null, i+1));
    else
        return i;
}
return next(0);
```

Comment: thank you. works great http://plnkr.co/edit/zwCYGQaxyGyr7kL6fLKh?p=preview updated